# Callback to solve unhandled promise, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, callback

I've solved the problem so my question is more of a theorical because i'm trying to understand what is happening under the hood and why do i need to make a callback on

```
return Promise.reject()
```

> This is the code that i have for authenticating routes

```
async customAuth(req, res, next) {
    let token = req.header('x-auth');
    try{
        const userByToken = await User.findByToken(token)

        const userByCreator = await User.findOne({_id: req.body.creator})

        if (!userByToken || !userByCreator) {
            return Promise.reject()
        }            

        else if(userByToken.tokens[0].token !== userByCreator.tokens[0].token){
            console.log('its here')
            return Promise.reject().catch((err)=>{
                res.status(401).send('why do i need this callback?')
            })    
        }              
        next()

    }catch(err){res.status(401).send("something happened")}
}
```

As you can see when i'm comparing userByToken and userByCreator i'm trying to call return Promise.reject() with callback. **If i try** to remove the callback it tells me in the console that i have **unhandled promise**. WHICH IS JUST WEIRD because this code

```
 if (!userByToken || !userByCreator) {
                return Promise.reject()
            }
```

Works perfectly fine, and sends the try block to catch directly **without** giving unhadled promise errors.

> The question

Why do i have to make a callback? like in theory, and why if i remove callback it tells me that its unhandled promise?

P.S
Seems like the problem can also be solved

```
const rejected = await customAuth(Promise.reject('promise was rejected'));
return rejected
```

But still then why does this code work,

```
 if (!userByToken || !userByCreator) {
            return Promise.reject()
      }
```

but when i try to put in comparasion IF block it says unhandled?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "why do I have to make a callback" or "Promise.reject() with callback"?

Comment: Do you realize that `return Promise.reject()` does not cause it to go to the `catch` block in this function?  That just returns a rejected promise from this function.  Now, if you did `throw new Error("some error")`, that would go to your `catch` block here.

Comment: I mean why when i say if(!userByToken){return Promise.reject()} works good BUT if i try to put the same return Promise.reject inside of IF block when comparing tokens its deemed as "not good and need to make a callback

Comment: Can you show us how `customAuth()` is called?  That's where these rejections would need to be handled if you're going to return a rejected promise.

Comment: just put it in the route as a function, the problem is not there for sure. The answer below gives a somewhat more concrete explanation, i'm just wondering how can i reach outter catch by second reject

Comment: Please see my answer.  The "unhandled rejection" error probably comes because the caller of `customAuth()` which is sounds like is an Express router doesn't handle the rejected promise you return from it because it doesn't expect any return value.  So, you have to stop returning a rejected promise at all and handle it within the function.

Comment: "*The code `return Promise.reject()` works perfectly fine, and sends the try block to catch directly*" - no, it does not. `await Promise.reject()` might have done that. A `return` never ends in the catch block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that when you are doing `return Promise.reject()`, you want your code to go to your `catch()` block, but `return Promise.reject()` just returns a rejected promise from the function.  It doesn't go to your catch block.  Instead, you could use `throw` like this:

```
async customAuth(req, res, next) {
    let token = req.header('x-auth');
    try {
        const userByToken = await User.findByToken(token)

        const userByCreator = await User.findOne({_id: req.body.creator})

        if (!userByToken || !userByCreator) {
            throw new Error("missing userByToken or userByCreator");
        }            

        else if(userByToken.tokens[0].token !== userByCreator.tokens[0].token){
            console.log('its here')
            throw new Error("user token doesn't match creator token");
        }              
        next()

    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(401).send("something happened");
    }
}
```

What you may have confused is that your try/catch will catch a rejected promise that you are using `await` on or it will catch a `throw`, but it won't catch `return Promise.reject()` because you're explicitly returning that.

So, when you do `return Promise.reject()` and thus return a rejected promise and the caller has no `.catch()`, then you get an unhandled rejected promise.

Comment: hmm very interesting. Thanks for your explanation, highly appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I'm wrong

```
Promise.reject()
```

can't catched by `try / catch`,
it can only catched by 
`somePromise.cateh(() => {})`,

if you want catch it in the outer catch,
just `throw new Error()` is ok，
no need of `return or promise.reject`